# escape characters with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that opens up a browser window:

```
function startmonitor(camerahash, cameraname, cameraflashquality, cameramotion)
{
    window.open("mydir/file.php?user="+'<?php echo $id_hash; ?>'+"&camera="+camerahash+"&name="+cameraname+"&quality="+cameraflashquality+"&motion="+cameramotion, "Webcam_monitor");
}
```

cameraname is passed in from a button in html:

```
<button id="monitor" onclick="startmonitor('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>', '<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>', '<?php echo $camera_quality_flash; ?>', '<?php echo $camera_motion; ?>');">Start Camera</button>
```

cameraname does take special characters.  Such as `Al's camera`.  Because of the special character it messes up the window.open line.  Anyone have ideas how I can rewrite the window.open line to accommodate this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [encodeUri](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)

```
function startmonitor(camerahash, cameraname, cameraflashquality, cameramotion)
{
    window.open(encodeUri("file.php?user="+'<?php echo $id_hash; ?>'+"&camera="+camerahash+"&name="+cameraname+"&quality="+cameraflashquality+"&motion="+cameramotion), "Webcam_monitor");
}
```

Edit:
Actually, because you are wanting to encode the apostrophe, you would need to use the [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) function around the variables you wish to escape. In this case it would be used around the `cameraname` variable.

```
function startmonitor(camerahash, cameraname, cameraflashquality, cameramotion)
{
    window.open("file.php?user="+'<?php echo $id_hash; ?>'+"&camera="+camerahash+"&name="+escape(cameraname)+"&quality="+cameraflashquality+"&motion="+cameramotion, "Webcam_monitor");
}
```

**Edit 2**
OK, it looks like, based on your comment below, that you need to escape `cameraname` before it enters your `startmonitor` function. So you would actually escape it in your button code and **not** in your function code.

```
<button id="monitor" onclick="startmonitor('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>', escape('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>'), '<?php echo $camera_quality_flash; ?>', '<?php echo $camera_motion; ?>');">Start Camera</button>
```

**Edit 3**
Wow - I'm retarded. Just encode with php's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function before outputting to the page.

```
<button id="monitor" onclick="startmonitor('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>', <?php echo urlencode($result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]); ?>, '<?php echo $camera_quality_flash; ?>', '<?php echo $camera_motion; ?>');">Start Camera</button>
```

Comment: Still can't seem to get it right no matter what I try. Firebug gives this error: `missing ) after argument list startmonitor('d17ddbf8795d7b7138976caa7d7456eeb957e38e', 'al's cam', '0', '2');`. It points to the column right after the `al's`

Comment: @Tom Pepernic 'al's cam' has got you there. The apostrophe in al's is closing your string.  Try 'al\'s cam'. An escape character won't be necessary if you're getting the value from an input, which I assume you are.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  User input created this camera name. But that value is shown to the user when they edit it as well.  So not sure I can escape the character.

Comment: Have you tried the `button` html that I posted in my second edit?

Comment: I did, same message except it now says: `startmonitor('7dfa2afbcee33086e1d69cac299c1c5c5efb560b', escape('al's cam'), '0', '2')`

Comment: Hi @TomPepernic. Unless there is a specific reason you need to encode in JavaScript, just encode the necessary url components with php before outputting to the page. The problem you are running into is exactly what Alex said, your string is being closed.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks.  If your retarded, what does that make me? ;)

Answer (score 2):

[There are 3 ways to escape special characters:](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)

- `escape()`
- `encodeURI()`
- `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: And the opposite are `unescape()`, `decodeURI()`, and `decodeURIComponenet()`.